# Why there is no protocol declaration in view controller's header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, datasource

I'm learning objective-c and I found the following code in my book. I've got 3 questions,

1. Obviously it conforms the protocol by implementing two required methods, but why this works without writing `<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>` in the header?
2. Which protocol it conforms, `UITableViewDataSource` or `UITableViewDelegate`?
3. Why there is no `UITableView.delegate = self`?

Here is the code,

```
@implementation ItemsViewController

-(instancetype) init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if (self) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            [[ItemStore sharedStore] creatItem];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
-(instancetype) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[ItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *items = [[ItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
    Item *item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    c.textLabel.text = [item description];
    return c;
}

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
}

@end
```

Appreciate your help in understanding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemsViewController` looks to be a `UITableViewController`. A `UITableViewController` instance is the default `delegate` and `datasource` for the contained `UITableView` accessed via `self.tableView`.

Hence there is no explicit marking of protocol implementation `<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>` and set `self.tableView.delegate = self` and `self.tableView.datasource = self`

You can however, choose to set different instance as `delegate` and `datasource` in that case you need to create that instance, implement required methods in it and assign it to the `tableView`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! When I set a different instance as a delegate or datasource, then do I need to explicitly declare '<'UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate'>' in that instance's class header if the class is not a sub-class of UITableViewController?

Comment: @wz366 Yes, it is a good practice to mark interface with implemented protocols.

Comment: @wz366 It is not mandatory as long as your class implements the delegate methods. Xcode might generate warning for not marking the class but app should not crash.

Answer (score 2):

**`1. Obviously it conforms the protocol by implementing two required methods, but why this works without writing '<'UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate'>' in the header?`**

The '<'UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate'>' in your header is just an indication to the compiler that you want to implement the delegate methods in your class. You will get warnings if you don't implement delegate methods that are marked as **@required**, but since most of the delegate methods are usually **@optional** your code will compile and run fine. That doesn't mean that you shouldn't add the delegates in your header though.

**`2. Which protocol it conforms, UITableViewDataSource or UITableViewDelegate?`**

Default it needs only `UITableViewDataSource` with these two functions must be defined

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

**`3. Why there is no UITableView.delegate = self?`**

It is there, check your `xib` you set delegate from the xib too. Right click the `UITableView` you will understand what I mean, without setting delegate the above methods won't work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! But when I need the UITableViewDelegate protocol? I did not use interface builder so I can't find a .xib file.

Comment: @wz366 Just press Command button and click on `UITableView` you can find `UITableViewDelegate` methods to be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @iphonic but for the first point.

The '<'UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate'>' in your header is an indication for the compiler that the instances of the class does respond to that protocols. That info is used by compiler as added info for type matching. For example, when you set delegate or dataSource properties for a table view.

If you don't write '<'UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate'>' in header of the class, and you write something like "tableView.dataSource = self", then you will get warnings. When you use IB or Storyboard you don't write that setting line. That's the reason you don't have to include the protocols declaration in class interface.

Comment: How does tableview find it's delegate if I don't write tableView.dataSource = self?

Comment: @wz366 I said "When you use IB or Storyboard". There, in IB, is the connection between objects. When the table view is created with coder, its properties (dataSource, delegate, etc.) are initialized.

Comment: BTW. If you are initializing in code a table view controller (no IB or SB), then a table view is automatically created as its tableView property and linking at the controller as dataSource and delegate. In that case, again, compiler doesn't have to do anything and doesn't need the declaration of protocols.